# Trying to save a file inside another file, Shell Script

Tags: shell

I have this command I am using to insert code in to file2 from file_code, after this line "INSERT CODE HERE":

```
sed 'INSERT CODE HERE/r file1' file2 > output
```

But I want to do this in shell script. So I need to declare the file_code in the script I write. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some one please help. There must be a way. I really need it

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed -i option to edit the file in place from the shell script

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: I actually want to have the file with the script so when I transport the script, other people don't need to worry about different files. If that is possible...

Comment: sed -i '/searchpattern/rfile1'  file2.

Comment: Sorry, Proabably I misunderstood your question. I don't think there's a way to insert complete file in a shell script.

Comment: yes but I still need to declare the file1 somewhere. I want to do it in the script. I want something like file1 = " #mycode "
And then I want to use that command. Let me know if that doesn't make sense

Comment: you can put the file outside of the script and initialize the file1 variable with the path to that file.

file1="/path/to/file"

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. Assuming you want including a file in script, I think define a multilined string will make it. Refer to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/how-to-add-newlines-into-variables-in-bash-script).